# Rock subgenre of "Darkness" by SPF1000

Tags: rock, identify-this-genre, metal

Listen to this song...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rs3WV3Fu-kw&t=

Its called Darkness by SPF 1000. It was in an episode titled "Battle of the Bands" from *The Grim Adventures of Billy & Mandy*.

I really like it and I want more music that kinda "goes in that style". The way it sounds is really awesome! I cant really say for sure what genre this is. Well, clearly its a form of rock, but what sub genre is it exactly do you guys think? Anyway, I would like a list of songs or bands (underground, popular, it does not matter) that sound like this in a way. As close to this song as possible. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This song would most likely be related to the *industrial rock* or *industrial metal* genres. These terms are commonly used interchangeably to describe the style.

In SPF 1000's bio on Last.fm, they describe their music with the phrase "Haunting vocals whisper through walls of guitar with precisely calculated samples", and these characteristics are associated with the industrial style.

Also in their bio, they state:

"SPF1000 has been compared to bands like Marilyn Manson, Ministry, Nine Inch Nails, KMFDM and Rob Zombie, because of the way they incorporate spooky music with catchy, traditional 'rock' hooks."

Each of those bands are considered to be industrial rock/metal, or to be heavily influenced by the industrial genre.

Wikipedia has a page of [industrial metal bands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_industrial_metal_bands). However, music in that genre can admittedly vary greatly. Searching for "industrial rock" might limit results to more accessible options.

Comment: Hi Rich!  Welcome to the site, and thanks for sharing your knowledge with us :)

Answer (score 1):

When I play this song on youtube it seems to be tagged with other songs of NIRVANA.
you'll find certainly more of this style from that group.

Comment: I'm not sure that's a good indicator.  This song is certainly not grunge, and doesn't have all much in common with Nirvana, a band that despised progressive rock's excesses.

Answer (score 1):

This has the broad scope and theatrical ambitions (some would say pretensions!) of progressive rock, the sound and vocal feel of hard rock, and the themes of horror rock.  The closest thing I can think of to it is [early Muse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YfRQXIJ3fEM), [Wolfmother](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySjXFjLTagQ), or maybe even [Rush](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f_2cgHHK3fc).

You might also try searching "progressive hard rock" or "horror rock" and seeing if you find anything that matches your tastes.  If you want any of those three pieces separately, it's not hard to find, but I don't know if there's a specific genre that consistently unites them.